# How to install xcode command line tools for Xcode beta alongside another installation?

Tags: xcode, beta, ios9

I've installed the latest Xcode beta (e.g. installs to /Applications/Xcode-beta.app) and builds in the beta release fail because command line tools for iOS 9 can't be found.  I've change the target xcode path as follows.

```
xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app
```

Then I figured I'd have to run `xcode-select --install` after changing the target Xcode app, such that it would bring in the iOS 9 tools and libraries.  But xcode-select just complains saying that the command line tools are already installed.

```
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

I've never installed the beta alongside an existing installation, so I'm not sure what to do and googling just turns up countless questions about xcode-select.  Help?

Comment: if the tools are already installed, maybe everything is already in place for what you need.  Is anything actually broken?  When you type in `xcode-select -p`, do you see the path you're expecting?

Comment: At first xcode-select -p wasn't showing the updated path.  Then after a reboot it was showing the update path but builds were still failing with linker errors (saying that the libz.tbd couldn't be found).  Apparently these .tbd files text placeholder files for library symbols and this build issue is currently known for some cases.  I'm not sure what fixed it, I did an OS X update, which might be what brought in the support for them, but now my builds work. :)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a known issue.  I thought this had to do with general xcode installation, but it appears to be a new feature in the build process to use .tbd files for library symbols.  I was actually getting an error saying that a particular .tbd file wasn't found.  I did an OS X update and a bunch of things looked to be going on the background after the update, eventually came back and my build worked.  Magic I suppose.